# laravel Filametphp get table data by auth user id

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I am working with filament php and I am stuck here as I want table data to be user specific and want to get loggedin user data only

```
    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {

        $user = Auth::user(); // Get the authenticated user
        $userId = $user->id; // Assuming 'id' is the user ID field in your user model
        return $table //I want to access this data by user ID 
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('user_id')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('title')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('slug')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('status')
                    ->searchable(),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: modify the query. There is some sort of eloquent query function available

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `modifyQueryUsing` method on a Table instance.

Read [here](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/listing-records#customizing-the-table-eloquent-query) for more.

For your use case it will be:

```php
    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {

        $user = Auth::user(); // Get the authenticated user
        $userId = $user->id; // Assuming 'id' is the user ID field in your user model
        return $table //I want to access this data by user ID
            ->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('user_id', $userId);
            })
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('user_id')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('title')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('slug')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('status')
                    ->searchable(),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ])
            ->emptyStateActions([
                Tables\Actions\CreateAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
```

But I suggest If you just use the `user_id` for this filtering, move it to the scope of the query modifier function instead of initiating it out of the scope and then using it in the function. Something like this:

```php
public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table //I want to access this data by user ID
            ->modifyQueryUsing(function (Builder $query) {
                $userId = Auth::user()->id;
                $query->where('user_id', $userId);
            })
            // ...

    }
```